# How to handle "iterable must not be null" Flatmap Rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am using FlatMap in my app for transform the items emitted by an Observable into  Iterables. I am getting "iterable must not be null".Because list is null.So I want to handle this situation.Can anyone tell me the solution.

```
flatMap(new Func1<Chapters, Observable<Page>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Chapter> call(Chapters chapterList) {

                        return Observable.from(chapterList);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Did you tried to `.filter(...)` before `flatMap`?

Comment: Filter only will work if the one of the item in the list is null.But if the list is null,the above mentioned error will occur.

Comment: Please, add more concrete code. It's difficult to understand about which list you are talking.

Comment: @Vusal,In the above example code, chapterList object hold the list of chapter. We can filter an item if the list chapterList contains null,But in my case chapterList object is null.How can I handle it?

Comment: I understood you. Try to return `Observable.empty()` if `chapterList` is null.

Comment: @Vusal,I try and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
flatMap(new Func1<Chapters, Observable<Page>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Chapter> call(Chapters chapterList) {
                    return chapterList == null
                        ? Observable.empty()
                        : Observable.from(chapterList);
                }
            })
```

Comment: It helped me lot.Thanks.

Comment: return chapterList!= null
                                ? Observable.from(chapterList)
                                : Observable.<Chapter>empty();

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to return an empty List object, just create an if statement and return a new List object using its constructor.

```
@Override
public Observable<Chapter> call(Chapters chapterList) {
    if (chapterList == null) {
        return (new Observable<Chapter>());
    }
    else {
        return Observable.from(chapterList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Flatmap will emit each item from its list of item.But what will happen,if the list of item is null.That situation is occurring to me.

Comment: You could add a 'blank' chapter to the Observable list.  I'm not sure what your definition of a blank Chapter object would look like though, so I can't provide exact code but it would involve creating at least one Chapter and adding it to an empty Observable<Chapter> list.